# How to make a field editable only after saving the record in ODOO

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8

I have a field in odoo. I want it to be non-editable during the creation of record. After saving the record, if we again edit it , then it should be editable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `readonly` attribute base on `id` field:

```
<field name='id' invisible='True'/>
<field name="field_name" attrs="{'readonly': [('id','=', False )]}"/>
```

Demo:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="session_form_view">
    <field name="name">session.form</field>
    <field name="model">openacademy.session</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Session Form">
           <field name='id' invisible='True'/>
           <field name="name" attrs="{'readonly': [('id','=', False )]}"/>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

`id` is a default field in odoo and it takes a value after creation of the record so `name` field should not be editable during creation of the record.